# Dapper Extension: class with composite fields, mapped to an individual table

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, dapper-extensions

I have the following classes:

```
public class Publication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
    public ProductContact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class ProductContact
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And the table associated with this structure, "Publications", has all these fields (included the properties of ProductContact).

If I try to insert a Publication row (with the ProductContact information included) the program throws an exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The member Contact of type ProductContact cannot be used as a parameter value
```

So, I added a mapper to map out the ProductContact properties to fields in the Properties table:

```
  public PublicationMapper ()
    {
        TableName = "Publications";

        Map(x => x.Contact.FullName).Column("ContactFullName");
        Map(x => x.Contact.JobTitle).Column("ContactJobTitle");
        Map(x => x.Contact.Email).Column("ContactEmail");

        AutoMap();
    }
```

With this mapper I get the same exception.

Then, I added the ignore statement for the Contact field, to tell Dapper to not include this element in the insert statement

```
            Map(x => x.Contact).Ignore();
```

In this case, I get another exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@FullName".
```

It indicates that Dapper is ignoring completely this property, and the mapping added in the previous step does not have effect.

Is there a way to map out the ProductContact properties to the table fields?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just an anonymous class `new { pub.Id, pub.Title,......, ContactFullName = pub.Contact.FullName, ContactJobTitle = pub.Contact.JobTitle,ContactEmail = pub.Contact.Email}`?  Though it sounds like `ContactFullName` should actually just be `FullName` to match up with the parameter name in your SQL.  Showing the SQL and the full Dapper call would also help here.

Comment: It's unfortunate that it can't/won't do that. Found myself in the exact spot, trying to show management that Dapper is the way to go to help reduce code and ease-of-use. Especially when objects and their data counterparts have different names. Ah well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible with DapperExtensions.

In [one of their issues](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/issues/27), they say

> Currently, we aren't planning to support nested objects. However, you
>   can create your own Mapper that will allow for skipping over the
>   nested object

I have tried a variety of approaches and different mapping classes and can't get anywhere - I don't think that they support any way to map nested property values *and* to ignore the property itself (which, if not done, will result in "cannot be used as a parameter value" error).

One approach would be to manually flatten your object into an anonymous class (as suggested by @juharr in a comment on your question), another approach would be to use something like AutoMapper to flatten your complex object into a flattened insert model.